# Does $\mathbb Z/{2}\times\mathbb Z/{2}$ have no maximal and prime ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Since  Maximal ideal needs different from Ring,but and other proper ideal that contain it.
But I did not found in this case.
For Prime Ideal  I must not equal Ring. and need $ab\in Ideal\rightarrow a\in Ideal$ or $ b\in  Ideal $ I did not found too  Does it both exist ?

Comment: Maximal ideals always exist (assuming Zorn's lemma is true). And maximal ideals are always prime.

Comment: ok,thank for confirm it's exist  ^ ^

Comment: Are you asking whether there is a prime ideal that is not maximal? If so, the answer is no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb Z_2 \times 0$ and $0 \times \mathbb Z_2 $ are two prime ideals of $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$. They are actually maximal because the quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2$, a field.

This happens in every finite commutative ring: every prime ideal is maximal, because every finite integral domain is a field.